# How to access Sharepoint communication site's document library via Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

Using `Microsoft GraphAPI` I can access `SharePoint` team site document library and lists but I can't access `SharePoint` communication site.

App permissions added in `Azure Portal`:

**Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Group.Read.All, Sites.Manage.All,
User.Read, User.Read.All, User.ReadBasic.All**

Endpoint used for accessing SharePoint team site:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives
```

I'm calling the same endpoint for accessing `SharePoint` communication site, but I got a response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": []
}
```

What permissions do I need to add for my app in `Azure Portal` on API Permissions tab for accessing SharePoint communication site documents and list?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you provided these permissions for Delegated permissionsand application permissions you are able to get the query results?
[image]

Here is the link for the [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), Hope this helps.